# Multiple Storyboards in WatchKit App

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, watchkit

Is there any way to use multiple storyboards inside a WatchKit app? From what I can tell, you can only use a single one which makes it difficult when working in a large team. The APIs available on `UIStoryboard` are as follows:

```
func instantiateInitialViewController() -> AnyObject
func instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String) -> AnyObject!
```

Neither of which support WatchKit objects. Additionally, the `WKInterfaceController` class method for reloading different interface controllers only takes an array of identifiers.

```
class func reloadRootControllersWithNames(_ names: [AnyObject],
                             contexts contexts: [AnyObject]?)
```

Based on all this information, I'm pretty positive that it's not possible. I wanted to ask the experts out there if you could confirm my suspicions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No WatchKit does not currently support multiple Storyboard files.

I believe this limitation is due to the early stages of the current complexities associated with running code remotely on iPhone and Storyboards on Apple Watch.

WatchKit automatically generates and configures the required Storyboard for you when adding a Watch target to a project. This storyboard includes your WKGlanceController and WKUserNotificationInterfaceController of which you only need one.

[Perhaps submit a feature request.](http://bugreport.apple.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I went ahead and filed a [feature request](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5059146466459648). Everyone else that comes by this question and comment, please dupe that radar if you'd like to see this feature supported.

Comment: @cnoon great I'm submitting a dupe now

Comment: Cool, they updated the radar:
"This has been fixed in the latest Xcode 7 beta."